# Rails: suggestions for simplifying controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, cancan

I think I might be approaching this wrong. Looking for advice from Rails community on Rails way to handle something like this:

I have a Reservation resource. Model attributes look something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: reservations
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
   ...
#  amount_received :integer
#  party_size      :integer          default(1)
#  user_id         :integer
#  event_id        :integer
#  confirmed_at    :datetime
#  edited_by       :integer
#  comped_by       :integer
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
   ...
```

A number of things can happen to these objects:

- it can be created
- payment can be applied to one
- it can be confirmed.
- it can be comped (internally by someone with proper authorization)
- it can be cancelled
- etc...

My problem is basic but how to handle these events? they are all part of an `update` action (well, except 1st and last) on the controller. My controller is getting squirrelly and starting to 'smell'. Right now I identify an "action" by adding a `param` and then checking for the existence of that `param` in the controller. Then depending on what it is I check that user is authorized for said action (though by action I mean a sub-action of update because they're *all* `update` "actions") and then, only then, do I call a method on the model `receive_payment(amount)`.

This is getting cumbersome though, because a user can update *their* reservation (cancel and change party_size) but they can't "receive a payment" or "comp" it, etc... I'm using Ryan Bates' Can Can gem for authorization but I don't know that it's helping me at this fine level...

For instance, the `flash` messages should be more specific, like `"Payment received from #{@reservation.user.name}"` or `"Could not comp reservation for {@reservation.user.name}"`

Piece of controller:

```
  def update
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    # authorize! :update, @reservation #handled by load_and_authorize_resource up top
    authorize! :accept_payment, @reservation if params[:reservation][:comped_by]
    @reservation.edited_by = current_user.id if params.has_key?(:amount_received)
    ... 
    if @reservation.update_attributes params[:reservation]
      redirect_to event_reservations_path(@reservation.event_id), flash: { success: "Reservation updated" }
    else
      render action: "show", error: "Error updating reservation"
    end
  end
```

Thoughts?

seems like there might be approaching this wrong?!?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in model and use it in controller like this.

```
def update
Reservation.method_for_all_actions(params[:some_parameter])
end
```

params[:some_parameter] should contain the type of action being done i.e

- it can be created
- payment can be applied to one
- it can be confirmed.
- it can be comped (internally by someone with proper authorization)
- it can be cancelled
        etc...

Then check in model which type of parameter[:some_parameter] is being passed and do the functionality.